# Probability distributions associated to the logarithm numeration system

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, stochastic-processes, convergence

The most elementary logarithmic numeration system is defined as follow. Any random number $X \in [0, 1]$ can be represented uniquely as
$$X=\log_3(A_1 + \log_3(A_2+\log_3 (A_3 + \cdots)))$$
with $A_k \in \{1, 2\}$ also a random variable if $X$ is a random variable. Let us introduce the sequence $X_n$ with $X_1=X$, as follows:

$$X_{n+1} = 3^{X_n}-A_n, \mbox{ with } A_n = 2 \mbox{ if } X_n\geq \log_3 2, \mbox{ and } A_n = 1 \mbox{ otherwise}.$$

The above formula allows you to compute the digits $A_1, A_2$ and so on. Also $X_n\in [0, 1]$. Assuming $X_1 = X$ is uniform on $[0, 1]$, I am interested in the following quantities:

- $p_n = P(X_n < \log_3 2)$, and especially $p_\infty$.
- $E(X_\infty^k)$, $k=1, 2, 3, 4$.
- The limiting distribution of $X_n$ and whether it admits a
  non-singular density function.
- $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n\Big(E(X_n)-E(X_\infty)\Big)$

Any result, other than the ones I already discovered myself and listed in the next section, is welcome.

**1. Theoretical results obtained so far**

Probably the most fundamental theorem is this:

- If $X_n\geq \log_3 2$ then $P(X_{n+1}\geq \alpha) =
     \frac{1}{1-p_n}P(X_n\geq \log_3(2+\alpha))$
- If $X_n < \log_3 2$ then $P(X_{n+1}\geq \alpha) =
     \frac{1}{p_n}\Big[p_n -P(X_n\geq \log_3(1+\alpha))\Big]$

Thus
$$P(X_{n+1}\geq\alpha) = p_n + P(X_n\geq \log_3(2+\alpha)) - P(X_n\leq \log_3(1+\alpha).$$ 
Here $\alpha\in[0, 1]$. Many simple results can be derived from this formula, in particular:

- $P(X_2\leq\alpha)=\log_3\Big[\frac{1}{2}(1+\alpha)(2+\alpha)\Big]$
- $p_2 = \log_3\Big[\frac{1}{2}(1+\log_3 2)(2+\log_3 2)\Big]$
- $E(X_2) = \frac{2+\log 2}{\log 3} - 2$

and more generally formulas like these ones, for $n>1$:

$$P(X_n <\alpha) = -p_{n-1} -(n-1)\log_3 2 + \log_3 \prod_{i_1,\cdots,i_{n-1}} B_{i_1,\cdots,i_{n-1}}$$

$$p_n = -(n-1)\log_3 2 + \log_3 \prod_{i_1,\cdots,i_{n-1}} C_{i_1,\cdots,i_{n-1}}$$

with (for instance)

- $A_{i_1,i_2,i_3} =\log_3(i_1+\log_3(i_2+(\log_3(i_3 +\alpha))), $
- $C_{i_1,i_2,i_3} =\log_3(i_1+\log_3(i_2+(\log_3(i_3 +\log_3 2)))$.

All indexes $i_1,i_2,i_3$ and so on take only on two values: $1, 2$.

In short all the quantities of interest can be computed recursively. Note that these results are from me, if you see any error or typo, please let me know.

**2. Distribution of $X_{\infty}$**

It is very well approximated by $P(X_\infty <\alpha) \approx \sqrt{\alpha}$. Note that $\alpha\in [0,1]$.
Below are the empirical percentile distributions for $X_1$ (uniform), $X_2, X_3$ and $X_{40}$.

[image]

Below is the error between the empirical distribution of $X_{40}$ and its approximation based on a square root distribution on $[0, 1]$:

[image]

This a remarkable chart. I had expected to be fractal-like, highly chaotic as this is the case for the nested square root system, see [here](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/math-fun-infinite-nested-radicals-of-random-variables).

**3. Empirical results**

The chart below shows convergence of the first four moments $M_1,\cdots, M_4$, as well as that of $p_n$, starting with $X_1 = X$ being uniform on $[0, 1]$.

[image]

And here is some source code for the various computations:

```
$lg=log(2)/log(3);
$rand=sqrt(2)/2;
$m=40;           # X_1, ... X_m
$numbers=90000;  # sample size

open(OUT,">lognum.txt");

for ($k=0; $k<$numbers; $k++) {

  if ($k % 100==0) { print "$k\n"; }

  $x=$rand;
  $rand=3*$rand-int(3*$rand);  # uniform deviates
  $z=$x;

  for ($n=1; $n<=$m; $n++) {
    if ($z >= $lg ) { $digit=2; } else { $digit=1; } 
    $z2=$z*$z; ## to compute variance
    $z3=$z*$z2;
    $z4=$z*$z3;
    if ($n==40) { print OUT "$k\t$x\t$n\t$z\t$digit\t$z2\n"; }

    if ($digit==1) { $adigit[$n]++; }
    $az[$n]+=$z;
    $az2[$n]+=$z2;
    $az3[$n]+=$z3;
    $az4[$n]+=$z4;

    $z=3**$z - $digit;

  }

}
close(OUT);

open(OUT,">lognum2.txt");
```

Comment: I am also interested in asymptotic results or simple recurrence relations to compute the various quantities.

Comment: I would considere this much more mathematics than statistics, eventthough there is use of 'probability' the application is theoretic and not applied mathematics.

Comment: I hesitated posting it in math.stackexchange. Yes it is probabilistic number theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your theoretical result is very straightforward. If we have

$$X_{n+1} = 3^{X_n} - A_n$$

then

$$P[X_{n+1} \geq \alpha]  = P[3^{X_n}-A_n \geq \alpha] = P[X_n \geq \log_3(\alpha + A_n)] $$

and you can split up the condition $X_n \geq \log_3(\alpha + A_n)$ into conditional cases when $X_n \geq \log_3(2)$ and when $X_n < \log_3(2)$. This is a split up in regions.

$$\begin{array}{}
P[X_{n+1} \geq \alpha]  &=& P[X_n \geq \log_3(\alpha + A_n)] \\
&=& P[2 > X_n \geq \log_3(\alpha + 1)] +   P[ X_n \geq \log_3(\alpha + 2) \geq \log_3(2)] \\
&=& \underbrace{P[2 > X_n \geq \log_3(\alpha + 1)]}_{X_n<2} +   \underbrace{P[ X_n \geq \log_3(\alpha + 2)] \hphantom{\geq \log_3(2)}}_{X_n \geq 2} \end{array}$$

---

It might be interresting to consider the following continued logarithm:

$Y_n = \log_3(B_1 + \log_3(B_2 + \log_3(B_3 + ....)))$

where $B_i = A_i \text{ if } i \leq n$ and $B_i = 1 \text{ if } i > n$

and $Y_\infty$ has all $B_i = A_i$ and equals $X$.

The $Y_n$ are like the $Y_\infty$ but with the digits above $n$ removed. Your $X_n$ is an expression for the difference between $Y_n$ and $Y_\infty$, but taken to the power 3 repeated $n$ times.

Then $$X_n = 3^{3^{3^{\dots (Y_{\infty})}}}-3^{3^{3^{\dots (Y_{n})}}} = \log_3(A_{n+1}+\log_3(A_{n+2}+\log_3(A_{n+3}+ \dots)))$$

---

Inspired by that you could also find the coordinates $A_i$ or $B_i$ by slicing the section $[0,1]$ into pieces according to numbers $Y_n$

[image: split up]

It seems like the probability for the digit $P(A_n = 2)$ (the gray sections) decreases as $n$ is increasing, but the rate of decrease is slowing down for larger $n$.

For $n=16$, I computed the $Y_n$ for all possible $A_1, ... , A_n$. Based on that I computed the first $p_n$ and this gave on a log-log plot the following:

[image: pn]

Do we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} p_n = 0$ ?

What we see is that everytime these sections are getting split up into a black and a gray section. What is the fraction of gray for each split?

I am taking some jump and pose that

- the right section is the one that gets split into the largest part gray. The point of split $z_n$ follows

  $$z_{n+1} = \log_3(2+z_n)$$

  with $z_1 = \log_3(2)$

  The fraction of gray is $f(z_n) = (1-z_{n+1})/(1-z_n)$. This gives more generally as a function of $q=1-z$

  $$f(q) = \frac{1-\log_3(3-q)}{q} \underbrace{ \approx \frac{\frac{1}{\log(27)}q }{q} }_{\text{Taylor series approximation}} \underbrace{\approx \frac{1}{\log(27)  }\approx 0.3034}_{\lim q \to 0}$$
- the left section is the one that gets split into the smallest part gray. The point of split $z_n$ follows

  $$z_{n+1} = \log_3(1+z_n)$$

  with $z_1 = \log_3(2)$

  The fraction of gray is $f(z_n) = 1 - z_{n+1}/z_n$. This gives more generally as a function of $q=z$

  $$f(q) = 1 - \frac{\log_3(1+q)}{q} \underbrace{ \approx 1- \frac{\frac{1}{\log(3)}q }{q} }_{\text{Taylor series approximation}} \underbrace{\approx 1-\frac{1}{\log(3)  }\approx 0.0898}_{\lim q \to 0}$$

So we get

$$ 0.0897 < p_{\infty} < 0.3035 $$

The same technique can be used to refine the bounds by going further down the tree instead of just using the left most and right most sections. For the moment I do not see a more intelligent way to find bounds for $p_\infty$